# issue on creating child theme

Tags: child-theme

I want to create a child theme. But my parent theme is different from the child theme. Parent theme and child theme have 2 different styles. The parent theme is the LeadEngine theme and the child theme is Ave theme. Here is my child theme style.css file.

```
/*
 Theme Name: Ave Child
 Theme URI: http://ave.liquid-themes.com/
 Author: Liquid Themes
 Author URI: https://themeforest.net/user/liquidthemes
 Template: leadengine
 Description: Smart, Powerful and Unlimited Customizable WordPress Child Theme.
 Version: 2.7
 License: GNU General Public License
 License URI: license.txt
 Text Domain: ave-child
 Tags: responsive, retina, rtl-language-support, blog, portfolio, custom-colors, live-editor
 */
  @import url("../leadengine/style.css");
```

And after this code, there is child theme style code.
Here is my function.php file.

```
/**
 * The Liquid Themes Ave Theme
 *
 * Note: Do not add any custom code here. Please use a child theme so that your customizations aren't lost during updates.
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * Text Domain: 'ave'
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 */

 // Starting The Engine / Load the Liquid Framework ----------------
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

 function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
 }
 include_once( get_template_directory() . '/liquid/liquid-init.php' );
```

But it is showing an error.

```
Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle/wp-content/themes/leadengine/liquid/liquid-init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-content\themes\ave-child\functions.php on line 22

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle/wp-content/themes/leadengine/liquid/liquid-init.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-content\themes\ave-child\functions.php on line 22
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function liquid_helper() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-content\themes\ave-child\header.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-includes\template.php(723): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-includes\template.php(672): load_template('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', true) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-includes\general-template.php(41): locate_template(Array, true) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-content\themes\leadengine\front-page.php(13): get_header() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle\wp-content\themes\ave-child\header.php on line 10
```

Comment: Does "C:\xampp\htdocs\pyxle/wp-content/themes/leadengine/liquid/liquid-init.php" exist? Is that the correct path for it? What should the correct path be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error comes from the missing function - which I presume is included in the missing included file - check your file paths to ensure you are calling the include_once in the correct place.